# Using twitter with node.js and express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am currently trying to integrate a javascript file into an HTML page but I am having difficulties with errors arising when running the page through a node.js server. Specifically, the error is with the following code:

```
var Twit = require('twit'),
var client = new Twit({
      consumer_key: '',
      consumer_secret: '',
      access_token: '',
      access_token_secret: '',
      timeout_ms: 60*1000,
    }),
```

The error raise is that require is not a function. To resolve this I moved the above code into app.js but I am now unsure how to include `Twit` and `Client` into my javascript file? As the functions within my javascript file now cannot seem to access these variables.

Comment: Can we have the full error message please?

Comment: Use NPM.. either programically or package.json

Comment: error with the code included: ReferenceError: require is not defined, without it it just flags up that the use of twit or client isn't defined

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to use Node.js client-side.

This question is very similar I think. Trying using Browserify:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/2420327

Comment: I think that you should install require :
sudo npm install -g require

Comment: ideally, you should be doing this on the server. I did a similar thing with my webapp. mean without mongo. Here's the link if it helps https://github.com/binarybaba/influenza